# Wrong Item Id in Collection

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I have collection field type in my form. And I have problem with Id of a field. When page is loaded for example I've got three items in my collection. In this case they should have ID's 0, 1 and 2 but They've got 4, 5, 6....

```
<input type="text" id="form_crm_contact_person_contactPhone_4_value" name="form_crm_contact_person[contactPhone][4][value]">
```

Later when I add new item It has Id 4, and it would be okey when previous items would have correct Id's. But in this case new item is updating this old item instead of being a new one - when the form is saved...

Any ideas what can be wrong ? I have to say that in other collection in my application everything it's okey... Rest start with zero.

Comment: I'm guessing that you had some items and then deleted them?  Did you expect that the mysql auto increment column would start over at 0?  Cause it won't.

Comment: It has no connection with MYSQL auto-increment, for example this items in MySQL base has got ID's 34641, 34642, 34645.

Comment: Ok.  Bit of a mystery.  In your mappings do you have a indexBy setting for Person::contactPhones?  Assuming you are using Doctrine 2.

Comment: Logically you should never write an algorithm based on entities ids. If you want to introduce an order, or set an integer to an entity, you must add an integer column.

Comment: Yep, I'm using doctrine and I have contact entity with contactPhone relation to information_entity which is creating foreing key correctly in my base. Everything looks correct, the same like in other collections in this applications. For example in the same for I've got collection field with adresses and It's working correctly. I've got simply no idea why in this case items starts with 4 instead of 0... It's mystery indead...